# Can't connect Padrino to PostgreSQL db w/ activerecord

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, padrino

Trying to setup the Padrino web framework to connect to my local PostgreSQL database with the following info:

**databases**

```
       List of databases
| Name                   |  Owner
|------------------------|------------ 
| postgres               | postgres
| template0              | postgres
| template1              | postgres
|trustmob_ui_development | postgres
|trustmob_ui_production  | postgres 
|trustmob_ui_test        | postgres
(6 rows)
```

**config/database.rb**
[https://gist.github.com/1046031](http://gist.github.com/1046031)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[:development] = {
:adapter => 'postgresql',
:host => 'localhost',
:port => '5432',
:database => 'trustmob_ui_development',
:username  => 'postgres',
:password  => ''
}
```

When I try to run **`padrino rake ar:migrate`** I get the following error. Full error Gist here: https://gist.github.com/1046044

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/....
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I get Padrino to see/talk to the databases?

~Dan

Answer (score 1):

Have you call ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect with Navicat or other programs with your code?

The config is correct? Check your settings through `postgresql.conf`